# (Apache + SVN) Group/IP-based Authentication/Authorization

Tags: apache, authentication, svn, ldap, authorization

Assuming each user has a regular **user-account** "test" and an individual **admin-account** "test-adm" for a dedicated part on the server.

I want to grant access to an area on the server (SVN repository) when the user comes with an "**admin-account**" from a **defined ip adress range**. At the same time, this **admin-account** should have no write access to the rest of the server.

This **admin-account** should not work for the secured area from outside the **ip adress range** but there are other (LDAP) user groups that should be allowed to access the secured area with their **regular user account**.

Is there any approach to implement the concept of mutual exclusion in the scope of user access restriction within Apache?

---

[Access Matrix to a "secured" repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYHR6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to grant access to an area on the server (SVN repository) when
> the user comes with an "admin-account" from a defined ip adress range

IP-based ACLs are out of scope for SVN's [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) - it knows only "user", "group", "path inside repo"entities

> At the same time, this admin-account should have no write access to
> the rest of the server.

This is also a responsibility of (Apache) backend, not SVN-part

> This admin-account should not work for the secured area from outside
> the ip adress range but there are other (LDAP) user groups,

You have even worse case - SVN can use usernames from another authorization layers in authz-file (even LDAP|AD), but [haven't access to LDAP-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323405/subversion-with-ad-groups-with-linux), you have to transfer LDAP-groups to SVN (but [some solutions](https://bitbucket.org/whitlockjc/jw-tools/src/e3396390e99bfbc566a4e8423a123abb4c00d655/sync_ldap_groups_to_svn_authz/?at=default) already exist)

And when|if single user may have two roles (ro or rw), depending on conditions, it's job of authorization-subsystem outside of SVN to represent it as different users, you have to ask LDAP-guru about possibilities (this will be easier and faster, than include in another group and sync groups with SVN)